# Как запустить и остановить событие одной кнопкой? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка которая запускает событие(меняет рандомно цвета елементов методом setInterval()), а при повторном клике останавливает событие(но не сбрасывает). Если еще раз кликнуть - событие продолжить свой процесс.

У меня при повторном клике накидает ту же функцию. Не пойму как работает и куда писать метод clearInterval().

Подскажите пожалуйста

```
document.getElementById('changeBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    setInterval(changeColorBtn, 2000);
    clearInterval(changeColorBtn)});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var timer;
document.getElementById('changeBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (timer)
    timer = clearInterval(timer);
  else
    timer = setInterval(changeColorBtn, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я так понимаю что в данном случае идет от обратного, изначально остановка, а после идет таймер. я правильно понимаю?)

Comment: @TarasYurovskiy Не совсем. По первому клику таймер будет запущен, так как изначально переменная `timer` - неопределена, то есть `false`.

Comment: Аааа, вот оно что! еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

первое - это то, что Вы неправильно пытаетесь остановить `setInterval`. так правильно:

```
const intervalID = setInterval(changeColorBtn, 2000); //при запуске в intervalID передается/возвращается ID (ссылка), по которому надо обращаться к запущенном интервалу
clearInterval(intervalID)); //чтобы остановить нужно в clearInterval передать ID запущенного интервала как аргумент
```

второе - чтобы знать, запущен интервал или нет, нам нужно всегда где-то записывать/сохранять **состояние** этого интервала (запущено ли что-то, или нет). это можно реализовать многими способами, но мой коллега **@Igor** меня опередил и уже написал вариант ответа. еще несколько вариантов сохранения **id** интервала:

- через замыкание внутри лексичесого окружения исполняемой функции
- где-то в атрибутах блоков (`data-interval="3434"`)

Comment: Спасибо за обширный ответ. Буду иметь ввиду)